# Knowing Page Size of HTML Content- Word Document

Tags: asp.net, html, ms-word

I have generated HTML Content and I am writing it to a word File. I want to Know How many Pages it will take when Written to the Word Document.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be answered in a general way. Font sizes, paper size, margins, layout etc. are to be taken into account, and the exact font rendering may also differ (kerning etc.). Therefore, just create the Word document (you could use WordML) and let word compute the number of pages for you.

Comment: Actually I want to Add Header and Footer Per Page, can u suggest some way to achieve it

Comment: Basically WordML is just a Word document as plain XML. Assuming that you've got XHTML as source, you can create a XSL transform which converts the HTML as needed into a WordML document, including footnodes or anything else you like.

Comment: Useful links:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212812(office.11).aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/HTMLtoWordML.aspx

3rd-party component capable of doing this:
http://www.aspose.com/categories/file-format-components/aspose.words-for-.net-and-java/default.aspx